# How to Explain Taking the Summer Off?

Tags: resume, internship, websites

We're nearing the summer when internships are crucial for budding developers, and I have yet to receive more than a handful of interviews. I had an internship at a fantastic company last year, but unfortunately, I was still inexperienced and spent much of the summer in overwhelmed catch-up-mode. I feel like this might have damaged my chances as I haven't heard from them for a return interview. I loved the work, but I had a hard time wrapping my head around what was probably frustratingly simple to them. I've studied a bit more and appreciate the scope of what I was working on, but I still feel under-prepared for actual software engineering. This coming fall, I would be taking a formal class on the subject, and I would feel much more comfortable assuming another internship next summer.

I know that I would be developing over my break, so I know to put those on my resume. I have a couple of projects for clients and myself that I've been wanting to work on. Very specifically, I also want to run a sort of day-camp or community outreach to teach kids how to code and use the Arduino. Basically, my time would be very well-documented and demonstrable, but how do I bullet-point these projects if it ends up this way? I feel like an impressive first internship followed by a flimsy "I took the summer off" blank space on a resume is hard to pitch. (Not the least, explaining it to family.) I could maintain the blog portion of my portfolio website, and I know more and more recruiters are accepting hyperlinks on resumes, but how can I be sure they saw it before throwing my resume in the rejected pile?

Comment: You're not actually taking the summer off, so why would you say you did or leave a blank space? Just list the 'puter camp and other relevant projects in your resume like you would an internship. Am I missing the problem?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. The "blank space" comment was because a lot of people say they worked on "projects" and didn't. I'm specifically asking how to bullet point these projects and what sort of header you would be encouraged to read, and is it appropriate to maintain a blog with a link in the resume for details if the reviewer wants to cross check that I did do them?

Comment: Why can't you just say that you did projects and actually prove it by linking to code or any other form of documentation, like a blog detailing the nuke you built from an arduino? A section with work experience and personal projects is normal, I doubt that they'd look too much into why you didn't have an internship one particular summer: it's about the total picture.

Comment: I'm not very good at writing a resume, so I couldn't tell what was acceptable and what just seems out of place. Particularly, how much recruiters actually look over links you provide was a concern. If they do, I'm happy to showcase those. A lot of resume advice is to keep it simple, bland, and formatted to avoid frills. (In academia, especially, we're supposed to keep it formatted.) If formatting isn't an issue, I agree it's not much of a question. Thank you for the Arduino Nuke idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a couple of projects for clients and myself that I've been
>   wanting to work on.

You have people willing to pay you to develop code. That is what you put on your resume for the summer period.

Yes internships are great, but there is nothing wrong with taking a summer break to make money developing code. Plus this keeps the customers happy.

> Very specifically, I also want to run a sort of day-camp or community
>   outreach to teach kids how to code and use the Arduino.

If you do this, put on your resume that you ran a week long camp and taught X kids how to program the Arduino.

What you are proposing is a step-up from the students who will spend the summer flipping burgers or making pizza. You will be working with computers.

You could also look for a local no-profit that will want a volunteer to help them with their computers. Or you could take a class in the summer so that you can graduate early.

Also: most recruiters I know never follow the links on a resume, and most people that see the resume at a company will see it after it ha been turned into a text file. Yes they can check a link by cutting and pasting it, but they might not. The words you say on the resume will always be more valuable than the info on the far side of the link.

Comment: Thank you. I was worried people wouldn't want to follow links. After all, they're probably looking at dozens of internship resumes. Quantifying it (how many kids, what, where, etc) is good advice. I'll do that.